# how to get all values into a single variable from query?

Tags: php, mysql

- I want to display all the values present in ftext field i want to
  display all values into single variable like $spd.
- When i print this variable $spd it displays only one (ftext)value.but ftext
  contains multiple values.
- so please help me how to display all values using $spd variable

  Thanks in advance...!

  ```
  $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ftext from projectfield");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
  $spd = $row['ftext'];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time variable updates so it contains only last values. Below approaches resolve it:-

```
#Either print all values     
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ftext from projectfield");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  echo $spd = $row['ftext'];
}
```

or

```
# or hold ftext in array and then use this 
$spd = array();
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ftext from projectfield");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $spd[] = $row['ftext'];
}
foreach($spd as $val){
  echo $val;
}
```

Comment: may i know echo $val; it will works  outside foreach...?

Comment: @hameed you can print things outside loop like print_r($spd), but for each value you need to print in loop foreach, else it will provide only last value

Comment: thank you @Rakesh Kumar..i want to pass that variable into another array beacuse to send that value into html file so when i print test1 into html file i want to display all values from $val variable  this is my array  $troll=array(test => post['pro1'], test1 => $val);

Comment: @hameed it depends how you want to print, you can use this also $troll=array(test => post['pro1'], test1 => implode(",", $spd));

Answer (score 1):

you can use id as index

```
$spd = array();
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ftext from projectfield");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $spd[$row['id']] = $row['ftext'];
} 
foreach($spd as $key =>$value){
  echo $key." ".$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a single value because you are running a loop on the row that came out in the query. and saving it in the `$spd`. so only the last ftext is saved as all other are rewritten every time the loop runs.

What you can do is append the data to `$spd` with a delimiter instead of assigning it.

`$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ftext from projectfield");
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $spd .= $row['ftext'].",";
}`

and echo it.